# Using CHAR(24) as primary key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I'm working on application with RFID technology.

I have MySQL table where I store RFID Tag information. RFID Tag is an electronic device with unique code (called EPC - Electronic Product Code) which is 12 byte (96 bit) long. In "RFID bussiness" EPC typically is represented by 24 character string in hex format and I want to store these EPC in string format.

I would like to know how much it affects performance to use such a large field (24 characters) as the primary key. I could store them also as 12 bytes or even three Int32's.

I'm expecting 10000-20000 rows in that table and most queries will join on that field anyway.

Comment: that size table is relatively tiny so the initial performance hit will probably be minimal. Assuming you have some competent general indexing `:)`

Comment: Why does this have to be the `PRIMARY` key? Why cant you have an AutoIncrement primary key as standard and then this unique RFID column as a [secondary] `UNIQUE KEY`?

Answer (score 1):

The performance impact depends on queries, not storage. So the answer would require you to evaluate specific queries, which you have not shared in your question.

You only mention that most queries would join on that field (i.e. the primary key). It's likely that the advantage of joining on the primary key would be greater than the disadvantage of using the string. But that's a general guideline, it still doesn't address any specific query.

If you want to make the joins a little faster, then use a binary collation for the string. It allows string comparisons to be done with one `memcmp()` internally. If you use one of the traditional collations, that will force string comparisons to be done character-by-character with lookups into the collation.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE RFIDTagInformation (
  RFID CHAR(24) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin,
  -- other columns...
  PRIMARY KEY (RFID)
);
```

Or:

```
CREATE TABLE RFIDTagInformation (
  RFID BINARY(12),
  -- other columns...
  PRIMARY KEY (RFID)
);
```

Make sure the columns that it joins to in other tables are encoded with the same character set and collation, or else the joins will cause table-scans.